# "The perfect cure-free worries scattered mind."

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, grammaticality-in-context, semantics

"The perfect cure-free worries scattered mind."

This is a sentence I heard from the video *Stress Management Strategies: Ways to Unwind*

(at **1:23** -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fL-pn80s-c)

I couldn't understand what it means here. Is 'worries' the subject and 'scattered' the verb? If so, I couldn't see how it made sense in the context. Does 'cure-free' means that the worries are incurable? And how can such worries be perfect and the mind be scattered by the worries?

I'm not sure if I misheard the words... Please share with me any of your thoughts on this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a mis-hearing of a video sound track.

Comment: The speaker gabbles and has a strong American accent.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's 'the perfect cure for your worried scattered mind'. We don't normally like being made to watch and hear videos, as they are often annoying in some way, (e.g. the voice, as in this case). It is probably helpful to turn on the closed-caption subtitles.

In this case they have mis-spelled 'your' as 'you'. Maybe a computer makes the subtitles?

[image]

Comment: I see. I didn't know there's this upspoken rule here...Thanks much for the clarification.
Listening is a crucial part of my English learning process, but I guess I have to go elsewhere to deal with it. And yes, I believe the subtitles are made by computer.